# Can a high level Archer/Ranger catch an arrow fired at them?

Tags: dnd-5e, house-rules

Let’s say a highly skilled level 15 archer of whatever flavour is shot at by an enemy archer. Without using the gloves of missile snaring, could you have your archer use his reaction to catch the arrow?? Especially if the enemy archers shot misses your AC. I would expect some sort of Dex or Dex save for that.

Comment: Are you asking if this is possible under Rules as Written or if it would be balanced to allow  it as a house rule? If the second you will need to add a few more details on how you think the houserule will work.

Comment: I guess I’m asking the second one but I’m too new to D&D and that’s why I’m asking for suggestions on how it would work

Answer (score 6):

**No**

What you are suggesting is already part of the [monk](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Monk#content) class, it is called deflect missiles. Replicating the abilities of another class is very much outside of the rules. You could only do it via DM fiat or homebrew.